# Selecting multiple rows where column value on some of them is the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've seen other posts about this topic, but I'm pretty bad with SQL, so I can't figure how to adapt it to my problem, so, here goes:

I've got a table Commissions, like this:

```
Id || No || GroupNo || Type || CreationDate || Details || Workshop

1     45      2        TypeA      15:50         Hello.    NiceRepair
2     50      2        TypeA      15:50         Hello.    QuickFix
7     85      3        TypeA      16:26         Howdy.    NiceRepair
```

I want to select the `GroupNo, Type, CreationDate and Details` fields, but I'm having trouble.

Tried to `Order By GroupNo` but it caused an error.

How can I build a select statement that will return something like this: (single row, not only for id = 2 but for all ids > 0)

```
GroupNo || Type || CreationDate || Details

   2       TypeA     15:50         Hello.
   3       TypeA     16:26         Howdy.
```

Comment: Please elaborate . . . Why doesn't `select GroupNo, Type, CreationDate Details from Commissions` do what you want?

Comment: It selects the two rows, and I only want 1 entry on the gridview which I'm redirecting the data to, sorry, kinda forgot to mention that., I edited the post, should be more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for the Group By, a simple DISTINCT should do the trick

```
Select Distinct GroupNo, Type, CreationDate, Details
 From YourTable
```

If you are still getting multiple rows

```
Select GroupNo
      ,Type = max(Type)
      ,CreationDate = max(CreationDate)
      ,Details = max(Details)
 From YourTable
 Group By GroupNo
```

Comment: @danielhernandez Then they are not distinct.  Extra characters? ie. trailing spaces, CRLFs?

Comment: @danielhernandez Happy it helped

Answer (score 0):

```
select GroupNo,Type,CreationDate,Details
From table
group by GroupNo,Type,CreationDate,Details
```